# Is there any way to reduce execution time of this code?

Tags: c++, numbers, time-complexity

I am trying to find the sum of all the divisors of a given number 
But I am exceeding the time limit,help me to reduce the time limit of this code.

```
int a,count=0;
cin>>a;
for(int i=2;i<=a/2;i++) {
    if(a%i==0) {
        count=count+i;
    }
}
count++;
cout<<count;
```

Comment: Do you want to reduce the time complexity, or the execution time? They're very different things.  TLE usually means you want to reduce the execution time, not the time complexity.

Comment: Ok then ,I want to reduce execution time ...is there any way ?....and as I have mentioned this code calculates the sum of all divisors of the Number which is taken as input

Comment: Do you have any assumption regarding the value of `a`? maybe using multi threads will be useful here.

Comment: You can always trade speed for space and use caching or pre-computed values.

Comment: If you can get rid of that `if` statement and amalgamate that logic in to the the `count = count + i` part, you'll avoid branch-prediction failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say go up to sqrt(a). Each time you have a remainder 0, add both the i and a/i. You will need to take care of the corner cases, but this should bring down the time complexity. Depending on how large a is this should be faster. For small values this may actually be slower.

Comment: Why would it be slower?

Comment: Since you may have extra corner case checks e.g a is a perfect square, so you don't want to count the divisor and quotient (a=4 will result in 2 with your existing code and can result with 4 unless you have a check to count it once.) This additional check will need additional time , but I don't think you will be able to notice the difference.

Comment: What would be the corner cases ?

Comment: @Imran: Ah, I see.  But you save several modulos, as long as `a>4`, so it would only be slower for _very_ small values of `a`.

Answer (score 3):

You can make loop run to `sqrt(a)`, not `a / 2` if you would sum two divisors at time: `count += i + a / i`

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be optimized by prime factorization .

```
Let’s assume any number’s prime factor is = a ^n*b^m*c^k
Then, Total number of devisors will be = (n+1)(m+1)(k+1)
And sum of divisors = (a^(n+1) -1 )/(a-1)  *  (b^(m+1)-1)/(b-1) *(c^(k+1)-1)/(c-1)
X = 10 = 2^1 * 5^1
Total number of devisors = (1+1)(1+1) =2*2= 4
Sum of divisors  = (2^2 – 1 ) /1 * (5^2 -1 )/4 =  3 * 24/4  =  18
1+2+5+10 = 18
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help..I got the answer

```
     bool  is_perfect_square(int n) 
     {
     if (n < 0)
     return false;
     int root(round(sqrt(n)));
     return n == root * root;
     }
     main()
     {
     int t;
     cin>>t;
     while(t--)
    {
    int a,count=0;
    cin>>a;
    bool c=is_perfect_square(a);


    for(int i=2;i<=sqrt(a);i++)
    {
        if(a%i==0)
        {
            count=count+i+a/i;

        }

    }
    if(c==true)
    {
                count = count - sqrt(a);
    }
    count++;
    cout<<count<<endl;
    }


}
```